# Java Sockets - send data from server to client

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, client, server

I have a technogical question regarding Java Sockets.

For example lets assume I have one Java Sockets Server and n multiple clients.
Is it possible to send data from the Server to any or all Clients in nearly realtime?

More precisely:

- Is there kind of Listener which can be implemented in a Sockets Client?
- or do I need a loop in the client code where I ask every x milliseconds if there is a task for me?

Can somebody tell me what approach would be the best one?
And in addition if somebody has a code example I would be happy too.

Thanks!

Comment: The listener exists. It's called selector and can be used with java nio channels, i.e. ServerSocketChannel and SocketChannel in your case. Further you wouldn't need to loop in the first place, since read on io socket's inputstream blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can establish a Thread in your client which listens to the socket and waits. It will continue when it gets data from the server.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import java.net.Socket;

public class ResponseThread extends Thread {

    private final Socket socket;

    /**
     * Client is a selfmade interface which has no direct connection to socket communication.
     * i build it to provide start(), stop() and isRunning() methods.
     */
    private final Client client;
    /**
     * @param client encapsulated methods to check and manage the client status itself.
     * @param socket the socket which is connected to the server.
     */
    public ResponseThread(final Client client, final Socket socket) {
        this.client = client;
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ObjectInputStream reader  = null;
        try(ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
            while (client.isRunning()) {
                try {
                    // The thread will wait here until the server sends data.
                    final String line = (String) reader.readObject();
                    if (null == line || line.isEmpty()) {
                        client.stop();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    client.stop();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR Abort reading. Could not establish InputStream from Socket.");
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("FATAL Could not close Socket.InputStream.");
            }
        }
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd use Runnable or Callable over Thread. And the use of ObjectInputStream implies that all the clients use java.

Comment: I know, feel free to optimize it your way. I only want to show an example

Comment: thanks for the input, unfortunately I am bound to Java 1.6 and try-with-resources is not available for 1.6. :-(

Comment: and whats the class `Client`? I thought both Server and Client are based on the type `Socket`

Comment: Sorry, Client is a selfmade interface i used to offer status access and management for the whole client. Things like isRunning() stop() start() and so on.

Comment: I changed it to normal try-catch-finally

Comment: the Client interface sound interesting, can you share it with me? :-)

Comment: Currently its nothing more than an interface where i defined start(), stop() and isRunning() method-body.

and my main class implements it.

stop() does nothing more than:
    this.running = false;

So as you can see above, i check isRunning() every iteration of my read loop.

Comment: I implement a private method shouting() in my ClientImpl class (not part of the interface)  where i run a writing loop. If my System.in.readLine is NULL or empty i call stop() so my client will shut down.

probably i could give you a link to a repo where you can see the whole client and my simple mini chat server